# What is this pink target?

Tags: kerbal-space-program

Having set another satellite as a target, I have this pink marker on my navball:

[image]

What is it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That is your anti target.  It's the direction that points away from your target.  On the opposite side you should see a circular icon of the same colour which points towards your target.

Comment: Will thrusting prograde towards the target be the best way to reach it?

Comment: @fredley it really depends on what stage of approach you're in.  If you haven't switched to target mode (it doesn't look like you have, but I can't tell for sure), then you're better off setting up an intercept.

Answer (score 1):

They point towards (and away) from your target, the circular one is the prograde (towards the target) whilst the pointy one (shown in the question) is the retrograde.